# Is it possible to open a webpage on a tv using DIAL?

Tags: samsung-smart-tv, smart-tv

A lot of Smart TVs have DIAL and a lot of them have web browsers. Would it be possible to ask the TV to open the browser to a specific page using DIAL, kind of like you can tell it to open Netflix to a specific content id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [DIAL's FAQ](http://www.dial-multiscreen.org/faq)

> **Can I use DIAL on my 1st screen app to launch my web app's URL on the 2nd screen device via its browser?**
>
> Maybe. You need to work with the device manufacturer to see if the device's browser can accept input parameters (such as a URL) via DIAL, and whether the browser supports the feature set your web app requires.

Comment: Thanks for the info.